This page contains the following errors: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
I have a problem in the sitemap of my site
the sitemap page is displayed as it is:
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 5 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error:

https://ww1.m4uhd.tn/sitemap_index.xml


Questions in English only please

You need to get rid of those multiple blank lines at the start.
